# jQuery stopPropagation is ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to prevent all the click events (hiding/showing of elements in the HTML when clicked) unless a certain condition is met (the user has a certain word in an input element).

So i tried to add that logic to the click handler of the document or "html" but the click handler of the other element fired first because of bubble up.

So i tried attaching that logic to "*", and now that click handler fires first- but propagates it to the the other element too, ignoring stopPropagation, preventDefault and return false.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("*").click(function(event){
    if ($("#user").val() !== "admin"){
      console.log("1");
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();  
      return false;  
    }
  });
  $("#user").click(function(event){
    console.log("2");
    // do something
  });
});
```

1. Why "2" is written to the console after "1" when there shouldn't be any further propagation because of return false/stopPropagation?
2. How else can i achieve my goal using jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: `$("*").click` My heart just skipped a beat.

Comment: If you block all click events, how can the user click on the `user` element so he can enter `admin`?

Comment: @Barmar, the focus starts in user and i'm not letting it go anywhere else

Comment: @yair: Don't forget the ability to tab as well.

Comment: Yes i took care of that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) prevents the event propagating any *further* up the ancestor tree. However, it doesn't prevent the remaining event handlers on the current from being fired.

   To do *this* (prevent further propagation *and* prevent any further event handlers on the current element from being fired), you need to call [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) (instead, not *as well*).
2. Attaching an event handler to every element in this manner, and calling `stopImmediatePropagation()` (as well as `preventDefault()`) *will* prevent all clicks from having an effect; *providing* no event handlers are bound *before* (as handlers are executed in order; you can't undo a handler which has already fired).

   This doesn't make it *nice* though, as finding, enumerating over, and attaching a handler to every element is pretty costly.

   To make it *nicer*, your options are either:

   1. Attach a `click` event to `document`, and simply `preventDefault()` and sacrifice `stopImmediatePropagation()`.
   2. Check the state of `#user` in each event handler; you can ease the pain of this by rolling your own wrapper function;

      ```
      function checkUserState(then) {
          return function () {
              if ($("#user").val() !== "admin") {
                  then.apply(this, arguments);
              }
          };
      };
      ```

      ... use like so;

      ```
      $("#user").click(checkUserState(function(event){
          console.log("2");
      }));
      ```

   As noted in the comments, I'm purposefully avoiding the suggestion of using event delegation, as whilst allows attaching only one event handler instead of `n`, it doesn't allow you to `stopPropagation()` of events.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "*", ...)` would be a better way to implement this, since it doesn't have to find and bind handlers to every element.

Comment: @Barmar: ... that doesn't let you `stopPropagation` though, as the event has already bubbled to the `document`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the first nicer option, i thought we established attaching a click handler to the document won't help since it is fired last?

Comment: @yair: you're right; it will be fired last. However, this still lets you `preventDefault()` (e.g. prevent the form submitting, links opening etc.), it just won't be in time to prevent other event handlers from firing (this is what I meant about sacrificing `stopImmediatePropagation()`). It depends how important that functionality is (preventing event handlers from firing, *as well* as the default action).

Comment: Ah i see, so since the action of the other elements are hide/show/css etc. that option won't do since i need handlers for the other actions i'm trying to prevent. OK, thanks a lot! i learned a lot here :)